# Как используя javascript узнать номер счетчика Яндекс-Метрики который установлен на странице?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

Есть сайт-магазин, который имеет несколько поддоменов.
Движок сайта - один на  все домены.
 И шаблон тоже, тот же самый на все домены.
Но на все поддомены настроены и выводятся разные счетчики.

При отправлении форм необходимо сообщить о достижении цели:

```
  ym(XXXXXX, 'reachGoal', 'TARGET_NAME');
```

где XXXXXX - это номер счетчика

(https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/objects/reachgoal.html)

Т.е. возможно ли как-то из установленного счетчика выдернуть номер и указать его в этой функции?

вот сам код метрики:

```html
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
   (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)};
   m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
   (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");

   ym(XXXXXX, "init", {
        clickmap:true,
        trackLinks:true,
        accurateTrackBounce:true,
        webvisor:true
   });
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/XXXXXX" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если Ваш скрипт прямо в том же DOM документе, то можно вот так:

```html
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    (function(m, e, t, r, i, k, a) {
      m[i] = m[i] || function() {
        (m[i].a = m[i].a || []).push(arguments)
      };
      m[i].l = 1 * new Date();
      k = e.createElement(t), a = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], k.async = 1, k.src = r, a.parentNode.insertBefore(k, a)
    })
    (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");

    ym(ABC123, "init", {
      clickmap: true,
      trackLinks: true,
      accurateTrackBounce: true,
      webvisor: true
    });
    */
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/XXXXXX" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->


<script type="text/javascript">
  var ycounter = undefined;
  window.onload = function(e) {
    var myRegexp = /ym\((.+?), \"init\"/;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.scripts.length; i++) {
      var match = myRegexp.exec(document.scripts[i].text);
      if (match) {
        ycounter = match[1];
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(ycounter);
  }
</script>
```

Пример рабочий - я для этого код Яндекс-метрики закомментировал. Выводит в консоль значение счетчика: `ABC123`

Comment: Работает, спасибо!)

Answer (score 5):

Ниже функция, которая позволяет находить счетчик в любом случае (даже если он подключается не в HTML-разметке страницы, а во внешнем js-файле).

**Обновлено 10 декабря 2019г.**

```
/** Ожидание загрузки счетчика Яндекс.Метрики
 * @param {?(number|string)} ymCounterNum - номер счетчика, если известен
 * @param {function} callback - получает аргументами объект и номер счетчика
 * @param {number} interval - интервал проверки готовности счетчика
 */
function waitForYm(ymCounterNum, callback, interval) {
  if (!callback) return;
  if (!ymCounterNum) {
    let metrikaObj  = (window.Ya && (window.Ya.Metrika || window.Ya.Metrika2)) || null;
    ymCounterNum = (metrikaObj && metrikaObj.counters && (metrikaObj.counters() || [0])[0].id) || 0;
  }
  let ymCounterObj = window['yaCounter' + ymCounterNum] || null;
  if (ymCounterObj) return (callback(ymCounterObj, ymCounterNum), undefined);
  setTimeout(function () { waitForYm(ymCounterNum, callback, interval); }, interval || 250);
}
```

Для получения номера счетчика:

```
waitForYm(null, function (counter, counterNum) {
  console.log(counterNum);
});
```

Для сохранения объекта счетчика в переменную (для выполнения целей, и т.д.):

```
let metrikaCounter = null;
waitForYm(null, function (counter) { metrikaCounter = counter; });
/* ... */
if (metrikaCounter)
  metrikaCounter.reachGoal(/* ... */);
```

---

Вызывать функцию `waitForYm` можно в любой момент, хоть до готовности DOM.

Также можно ограничить длительность ожидания объекта счетчика, но я не вижу в этом смысла: одна простая проверка свойства раз в четверть секунды (и только до его обнаружения) не сильно грузит браузер.

**p.s.**: Старый ES синтаксис - для поддержки IE11 без полифиллов.

---

*Если с очередным обновлением Метрики скрипт перестанет работать - дайте знать в комментариях, пожалуйста.*

Comment: не работает. выводит null. А что такое Ya ?

Comment: @Vladimir, Раз выводит `null`, значит работает. Номер счетчика будет возвращать только если счетчик подключен к странице. Функцию я проверял на реальном сайте. `Ya` - объект Яндекс.Метрики, создаваемый её скриптом.

Comment: Вероятно, у тебя код вызывающий функцию отрабатывает раньше чем создается счетчик... это единственный вариант, который приходит в голову.

Comment: счетчик в коде выше, чем этот скрипт.. Это точно для нового кода метрики?)

Comment: Код обновлен (проверил на всех сайтах которыми я занимаюсь по долгу службы - все ок).

Answer (score 3):

```
Ya._metrika.getCounters()[0].id
```

[reachGoal](https://yandex.com/support/metrica/objects/reachgoal.html):

```
ym(Ya._metrika.getCounters()[0].id, 'reachGoal', target);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ym_counter_id = window.mainMetrikaId;
```

Надеюсь кто-то сильно сократит свои исследования. Я не совсем понял, но нашёл эту переменную в браузере: window.mainMetrikaId.

Для мультисчётчиков возможно не сработает.