# Код счетчика Метрики - в переменную. Возможно ли?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Я хочу отложить загрузку счетчика Метрики до момента, когда пользователь начнет скроллить страницу.

Я хотела бы использовать что-то такое:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (scl === false) {
        scl = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#ym").innerHTML = 'тут код счетчика ';
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Такой вариант с innerНTML, конечно, не позволит мне записать в блок #ym код счетчика метрики.

Есть ли способ это сделать? Может быть, импортом из другого файла?
Или еще как-то?

Мне пока не осилить такую задачу самой. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Код счетчика такой:

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika informer --> <a href="https://metrika.yandex.ru/stat/?id=111111111&amp;
   from=informer" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<img src="https://informer.yandex.ru/informer/111111111/3_0_FFFFFFFF_EFEFEFFF_0_pageviews" 
style="width:88px; height:31px; border:0;" alt="Яндекс.Метрика" title="Яндекс.Метрика: данные за сегодня 
(просмотры, визиты и уникальные посетители)" class="ym-advanced-informer" data-cid="111111111" data-lang="ru" /></a> 
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika informer --> 
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --> <script type="text/javascript" > 
(function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)}; 
m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)}) 
(window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym"); 
ym(111111111, "init", { clickmap:true, trackLinks:true, accurateTrackBounce:true, webvisor:true }); 
</script> 
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/111111111" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div>
</noscript> <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [Как используя javascript узнать номер счетчика Яндекс-Метрики который установлен на странице?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965603/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-javascript-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Comment: Обновил свой ответ в прилинкованном дубликате, чекнул на yandex.ru/news - получение номера работает исправно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно разбить код счетчика на две части, как здесь:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var html = `
  <p>html replacement</p>
  `;
  var code = `
    console.log("test");
  `;
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.innerText = code;
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(script);
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test here</div>
```

Comment: @Наталья Покажите "код счетчика" (в вопросе).

Comment: Дополнила вопрос кодом счетчика

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: Игорь, это всё интересно и замечательно само по себе. Спасибо. Но моя задача в том, чтобы код счетчика подгружался по событию прокрутки с задержкой в 1 секунду. Внутри функции, запускаемой по setTimeout, это, к сожалению не срабатывает

Comment: @Наталья Срабатывает.

Comment: Да! Руки у меня кривоваты, к сожалению :)) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Наталья Пожалуйста. Успехов.